# How to create clickable pin in MapControl on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

i had a following code in xaml

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Visibility="{Binding SwitchText}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredRestaurants}" SelectionMode="Single" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockInfoFriTheme}" 
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=ShowDetailCommand}" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

and a viewmodel

```
ShowDetailCommand = new DelegateCommand<ItemClickEventArgs>(async (args) =>
            {
                Restaurant restaurant = args.ClickedItem as Restaurant;
                MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(restaurant.toString());
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            });
```

That works perfectly fine when i click on the item, so i tried the same aproach in maps and it dosent work. From what i could google it the problem is that i cant use IsItemClickEnabled="True" anywhere here so what are my other options? Because id like to have the same functionality when i click on the pin.

So this is xaml from my other PivotItem:

```
<Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredRestaurants}"  >
                        <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel 
                            Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,1" 
                            Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding coordinates,Converter={StaticResource CoordinatesToGeopointConverter}}"
                            Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  >

                                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowFoodLocationDetails}" />
                                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

                                <Grid x:Name="FoodContentGrid"  Height="Auto" Width="Auto" >
                                    <Rectangle Fill="#FF3FC500" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
                                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" >
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="FoodLocationName"  Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                                <Path Data="M33.4916,35.3059 L42.1937,35.3059 L38.1973,40.6036 z" Fill="#FF3FC500" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="6.302" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="9.702"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </Maps:MapItemsControl>
```

So id be very gratefull for any suggestions on how to ivoke my commad.
Also a semi related question. Is it possible to use MapIcon in strictly MVVM architecture? Because it looked much better when i used Maps in code behind Views but im changing it cause having strict MVVM is currently more important